# Scala: wrong type inference when mapping Strings?

Tags: scala, type-inference

I'm trying to compile simple helloworld in Scala,
and get error "scala: value capitalize is not a member of Char"
Why does compiler think that newW is Char?

```
val dict = Map(
    "hello" -> "olleh",
    "world" -> "dlrow"
  )

def translate(input: String): String = {
  input.split( """\s+""").map(w => dict.getOrElse(w.toLowerCase, w).map(newW => 
    (if (w(0).isUpper) newW.capitalize else newW))
  ).mkString(" ")
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second call to `map` in `translate` is mapping across the value returned from `dict.getOrElse(...)`, whose type is `String`, which can be implicitly treated as an `Iterable[Char]`. Thus, the compiler is correctly inferring that `newW` is of type `Char` and complaining when you try to call `capitalize` on it. You're probably looking for something along the lines of

```
def translate(input: String): String = {
  input.split( """\s+""").map(w => {
    val newW = dict.getOrElse(w.toLowerCase, w)
    (if (w(0).isUpper) newW.capitalize else newW)
  }).mkString(" ")
}
```

**Update:** By the way, that will fail at runtime if `input` is an empty string - it needs at least one more check for safety.

Comment: Technically, `String` is not `List[Char]`, unlike Haskell. I think there's an implicit conversion between them.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what's happening:

```
input // is a string
.split( """\s+""") // is an Array[String]
.map(w => // w is a String, for each String in the Array[String]
  dict.getOrElse(w.toLowerCase, w) // is a String (returned by dict.getOrElse)
  .map(newW => // is a Char, for each Char in the String returned by dict.getOrElse
```